# How to print only exit code ,when java program gives exception(running java program from shellscropt)?

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have a java program which throws some exception,I tried executing it from shell script and printing 0 on failure and 1 on successful execution of java program.But It also printing the Exception onto console I just want to print exit code only.How to do this ?.Any suggestion are appreciated .

following are my Java program and script files
Test.Java

```
public class EchoTest {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    System.out.println ("scuccess Prasad Bezavada "+(2/0));
    }
}
```

Test.sh(script file)

```
java Test
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then echo "1"
else echo "0"
fi
```

getting the following out put

```
$sh Test.sh
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at EchoTest.main(EchoTest.java:3)
    0
$
```

Expecting output is like below(i.e just want to skip the exception message)

$sh Test.sh
0
$

Comment: a word of warning: every other system would expect a 0 for success and any other value for a series of error codes

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
java Test 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then echo "1"
else echo "0"
fi
```

Comment: Hi @t_thirupathi, thank for your response ,it is just returning 0(zero) in both success and failure cases

Comment: that's because $? holds the success code of the redirection (>) rather than the java sentence

Comment: @prasad That means there is some other problem with running java Test, so it is exiting with non-zero always (in which case the script outputs 0).

Comment: @malarres No, redirection does not matter. $? has the exit code of the last command and redirection is not a command.

Comment: then my other answer is more complex than needed. will remove right now

Answer (score 1):

you have to catch the exceptions. After that, you would be able to output exactly what you want. on your example:

```
public class EchoTest {
public static void main (String args[]) {
    try{
        System.out.println ("scuccess Prasad Bezavada "+(2/0));
    } catch (Exception e){
        // doing nothing is ok for your intended behaviour
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you might also want to consider catching even `Throwable` instead of `Exception`, as it includes also `Error`s (including for example `OutOfMemoryError`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you would like your Java program to return a value (either 1 or 0).
In our case we will consider that if an exception is thrown, 1 will be returned and 0 otherwise. Also, exception will be hid (which is a bad practice. You should always log exceptions at least if you are not willing to show it on screen)

```
public class EchoTest {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        try {
            System.out.println ("scuccess Prasad Bezavada "+(2/0));
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // log your exception here
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Once this is done then what you will need to work on is on getting java's output code.

```
java Test
output = $?
# do some logic here..
if [[ $output -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "executed"
else
    echo "exception thrown"
fi
```

Finally, this will indeed return either 1 or 0 depending on execution ignoring exception case, which is what you actually requested.